# Can't pass the RxSwift PublishRelay value from custom view

Tags: uikit, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I am trying to extend my KeyboardView view with rx action with no success. According to debugging with breakpoints value is passed to the relay but extension is not called despite further subscription in a view controller. What might be a problem and how to fix it?

```
final class KeyboardView: UIView {

    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    
    fileprivate let buttonTappedRelay = PublishRelay<ActionType>()
    
    private let digitButtons: [KeyboardButton] = {
        return stride(from: 0, through: 9, by: 1)
            .compactMap { $0 }
            .map { KeyboardButton(actionType: .digit($0)) }
    }()
    
    private let eraseButton: KeyboardButton = {
        let button = KeyboardButton(actionType: .erase)
        return button
    }()
    
    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        setupViews()
        setupConstraints()
        setupActions()
    }
    
    private func setupViews() { ... }
    
    private func setupConstraints() { ... }
    
    private func setupActions() {
        eraseButton.rx.buttonTap
            .asObservable()
            .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
            .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] actionType in
                self?.buttonTappedRelay.accept(actionType)
            }).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
        
        for button in digitButtons {
            button.rx.buttonTap
                .asObservable()
                .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
                .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] actionType in
                    self?.buttonTappedRelay.accept(actionType)
                }).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
        }
    }
    
}

extension Reactive where Base: KeyboardView {
    
    internal var buttonTap: ControlEvent<ActionType> {
        return ControlEvent<ActionType>(events: base.buttonTappedRelay.asObservable() )
    }
    
}
```

Comment: There's nothing in the code you posted that indicates a problem. Try putting `debug` messages in the chain and see if you can track down where events stop propagating...

Comment: @DanielT., I put breakpoints and found out self?.buttonTappedRelay.accept(actionType) is successfully called meanwhile ControlEvent<ActionType>(events: base.buttonTappedRelay.asObservable() ) is not. Although I've subscribed to buttonTap in further code in VC.

Comment: If a function isn't called, you can't get its output. You aren't calling the function.

Comment: @DanielT., could you please explain why it isn’t called. I send the value to the relay via accept func. Then I subscribe to Rx extension with the relay inside it. Where else should I call it?

Comment: This is a basic programming issue. In order to use the results of a function, you have to call the function. If you think you are calling the function, then show the code where that is happening.

Comment: @DanielT., thanks! I will add the VC code and show where I subscribe to keyboardView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is likely in code you haven't shown. Note that the below code compiles, runs and works:

```
final class KeyboardView: UIView {

    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    fileprivate let buttonTappedRelay = PublishRelay<ActionType>()

    private let digitButtons: [KeyboardButton] = {
        return stride(from: 0, through: 9, by: 1)
            .compactMap { $0 }
            .map { KeyboardButton(actionType: .digit($0)) }
    }()

    private let eraseButton: KeyboardButton = {
        let button = KeyboardButton(actionType: .erase)
        return button
    }()

    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        setupViews()
        setupActions()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func setupViews() {
        let stack = UIStackView(frame: bounds)
        stack.distribution = .equalSpacing
        stack.addArrangedSubview(eraseButton)
        for each in digitButtons {
            stack.addArrangedSubview(each)
        }
        addSubview(stack)
    }

    private func setupActions() {
        eraseButton.rx.buttonTap
            .asObservable()
            .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
            .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] actionType in
                self?.buttonTappedRelay.accept(actionType)
            }).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)

        for button in digitButtons {
            button.rx.buttonTap
                .asObservable()
                .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
                .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] actionType in
                    self?.buttonTappedRelay.accept(actionType)
                }).disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
        }
    }

}

final class ViewController: UIViewController {
    weak var keyboard: KeyboardView?

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        let keyboard = KeyboardView(frame: view.bounds)
        view.addSubview(keyboard)
        self.keyboard = keyboard
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        keyboard!.rx.buttonTap
            .debug("")
            .subscribe()
    }
}

extension Reactive where Base: KeyboardView {

    internal var buttonTap: ControlEvent<ActionType> {
        return ControlEvent<ActionType>(events: base.buttonTappedRelay.asObservable() )
    }
}

enum ActionType {
    case digit(Int)
    case erase
}

class KeyboardButton: UIButton {
    let actionType: ActionType
    init(actionType: ActionType) {
        self.actionType = actionType
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        backgroundColor = .red
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

extension Reactive where Base: KeyboardButton {
    var buttonTap: Observable<ActionType> {
        base.rx.tap.map { base.actionType }
    }
}
```

Comment: I sincerely thank you for the attention payed to my problem. You were quite right - the problem lied in further code - too sophisticated view model in particular. I fixed it and everything started just as I expected.